# Wordpress navbar-default menu with jQuery effect not working

Tags: jquery, wordpress, menu, navigationbar

I want to style my Wordpres navigation bar/menu so when you load the page the menu is kinda big, but when you scroll a little, the menu gets smaller with a transition. I'm making a wordpress theme with bootstrap integrated and im positive that jQuery is activated, because I dit a test - so thats not the problem. I have also changed $ with jQuery, so thats not the problem either...

Maby someone can spot the mistake:

CSS:

```
.navbar

.navbar-default {
font-family: "Fugaz One"; 
padding-top: 20px;
}

.navbar-default2 {
font-family: "Fugaz One"; 
padding-top: 0px;
}
```

PHP:

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) { 
        $('.navbar-default').addClass(".navbar-deafalt2");
      }
      else{
        $('.navbar-default').removeClass(".navbar-default2");
      }
});

});
```

And the navigation-bar that I'm trying to style:

```
 <nav class="nav navbar *navbar-default* navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="container" >
                <div class="navbar-header">

                <!-- .navbar-toggle is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">                 
                    <span class="sr-only"><?php _e('Toggle navigation','_tk') ?> </span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                   </button>

                <!-- Your site title as branding in the menu -->

                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>
              </div>

            <!-- The WordPress Menu goes here -->
        <?php wp_nav_menu(
            array(
                'theme_location' => 'primary',
                'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse',
                'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right', 
                'fallback_cb' => '',
                'menu_id' => 'main-menu', 
                'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker()
            )
        ); ?>

                <!-- .navbar -->
</div><!-- .container -->
```

Comment: For the record! - I didn't include any "transition" in the CSS, but it doesn't scale down at all :-/

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you didn't spell *default* correctly?

```
$('.navbar-default').addClass(".navbar-deafalt2");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I hadn't seen that one, but my friend pointed it out to me this morning. No progress :-/

Comment: I just tried your HTML with the JQuery selector you are using nothing is returned. Try an attribute selector such as this: `$( "nav[class*='navbar-default']" )`

Comment: I just figured it out - sort of! By styling the .css directly in .js, AND removing the "navbar" from the class, it worked. But I really want to target a whole class with the .js, so that i can change and style both navbar-default, the logo in it, the menu-buttons in it and so on, at the same time. 

ex. like:

$('.TheWholeMenu').addClass("sticky");

... It seems like the problem is that it wont recognize the "sticky"-class in the CSS? :-/

Comment: Oh, nice one! Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks :) might go with a white background and lorem ibsum for my hand in!

Comment: You my friend are the definition of class.

Answer (score 0):

I made a fiddle [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/td4uzyp5/1/)

you don't necessary need an add class but you can directly add some CSS to the navbar:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
        /* or replace .css with something else like: add/removeClass */
        $('.navbar-default').css('padding-top', '0');
    }else{
        $('.navbar-default').css('padding-top', '20px');
    } 
});
```

Maybe this wil help a little

Comment: Didn't know that, nice :) I tried it, and it doesn't work either :-/ Could it be something that happens because wordpress effects the menu? I have done this styling with another website (not wordpress!) and it worked like a charm...

I just put it online - it might help:

http://www.itu.dk/people/memb/Cykelhjemmeside/Index.html